# Select Random Values for Grouped Dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I'm no whizz at SQL. However I'm using the following query:

```
select count(*) as countis, avclassfamily
from malwarehashesandstrings
where behaviouralbinary IS true and
       avclassfamily != 'SINGLETON'
group by avclassfamily
ORDER BY countis desc
LIMIT 50;
```

I would like to select 3 random hashes from the malwarehashsha256 column grouped by the avclassfamily column.

The following query works, question over:

```
select count(*) as countis,avclassfamily from malwarehashesandstrings where behaviouralbinary IS true and avclassfamily != 'SINGLETON' group by avclassfamily ORDER BY countis desc LIMIT 50;

virustotal=# select m.avclassfamily, m.cnt,
        array_agg(malwarehashsha256)
 from (select malwarehashesandstrings.*,
              count(*) over (partition by avclassfamily) as cnt,
              row_number() over (partition by avclassfamily order by random()) as seqnum
       from malwarehashesandstrings
       where behaviouralbinary and
             avclassfamily <> 'SINGLETON'
      ) as m
 where seqnum <= 3
 group by m.avclassfamily, m.cnt ORDER BY m.cnt DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by m.avclassfamily order by random()) as seqnum
      from malwarehashesandstrings m
      where m.behaviouralbinary and
            m.avclassfamily <> 'SINGLETON'
     ) m
where seqnum <= 3;
```

If you want this in a column in your existing query, one method is:

```
select m.avgclassfamily, m.cnt,
       array_agg(m.malwarehashsha256)
from (select m.*,
             count(*) over (partition by m.avgclassfamily) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by m.avclassfamily order by random()) as seqnum
      from malwarehashesandstrings m
      where m.behaviouralbinary and
            m.avclassfamily <> 'SINGLETON'
     ) m
where seqnum <= 3
group by m.avgclassfamily, m.cnt;
```